# How to fix this Travis CI error that builds fine locally

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I upgraded from xcode 10.1 to xcode 10.2.1. I needed to change a zendesk pod to satisfy swift 5. This builds fine locally but when travis CI tries to run this command from travis.yml file:

```
set -e
./.travis/scripts/setup_profiles.sh
./.travis/scripts/deploy_beta.sh "${WORKSPACE}" "${SCHEME}" "${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}"
set +e
```

I am getting an error and this is from the raw logs:

```
âŒ  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework':

âŒ  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':

unexpected mutating task ('SetOwnerAndGroup travis:staff /Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetOwnerAndGroup travis:staff /Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework') (in target 'nanopb-iOS11.0')

unexpected mutating task ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/travis/build/xxx/mobile-ios/.build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework') (in target 'nanopb-iOS11.0')
```

Comment: Is your project public? Perhaps you should also post what your `.travis.yml` looks like or give a link to the travis build

Comment: This is a private project. There is a lot of sensitive data in my travis.yml. Is there a specific portion you would like to see? I am not very familiar with travis and it's yml file so please bear with me.

Comment: well it doesn't look like an error with the yaml file. Did you make sure the version of xcode your project requires is also supported on travis? What version of xcode did you specify in your yaml file? It could be that this is an xcode-specific problem and has nothing to do with travis. Please verify what travis supports. You will also get more help if we atleast know what your scripts are doing, but if they also contain private data, then I don't know how else to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had duplicate frameworks. After deleting the dupes, the CI ran fine.